Is it possible to do conditional data loading in pinescript?
I am wondering if i'm able to only load tickers under certain circumstances in pinescript so the whole script doesnt just break because one ticker doesnt exist anymore. I know this was not possible in v4 but is it possible in v5?
I have tried some basic if statements to no avail

You can use the ignore_invalid_symbol parameter of the security().

ignore_invalid_symbol (input bool) Determines the behavior of the
function if the specified symbol is not found: if false, the script
will halt and throw a runtime error; if true, the function will return
na and execution will continue. Optional. The default is false.

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

close_1 = request.security("BINANCE:ETHUSDT", "", close)
close_2 = request.security("ABC:DEF", "", close, ignore_invalid_symbol = true)

plot(close_1, color=color.green)
plot(close_2, color=color.red)

